# Rust: Failed to garbage collect incremental compilation session directory

Tags: rust

```
warning: Failed to garbage collect incremental compilation session directory `\\?
\C:\Users\linds\Desktop\advent_day_one\target\debug\incremental\advent_da
y_one-1ku18ek572o5z\s-g494tiepmq-1uzwqer-working`: Access is denied. (os error 5)
```

After running `cargo run`, I get the following error. How can I either hide or solve it?

Comment: May be a result of the files being cloud synced. Will look more into it

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You should probably avoid syncing anything in the `target/` directory if that's what you mean.

Comment: The issue is not a sync issue but rather a corrupted `target` file of sorts.

Comment: Fixed image issues. Thank you for letting me know @Jmb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue arises from trying to garbage collect the files in `target` whilst the cloud sync service is queuing them for upload to the cloud.

Just simply deleting the `target` directory will temporarily solve the `Failed to garbage collect incremental compilation session directory` issue, clearing the backlog of failed attempts to garbage collect, however, the issue can only truly be fixed by developing in a non cloud synced environment.

[Solution Reference](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/79532)